# How to interpret Random Effects Plot from mgcv

Tags: gam, mgcv, random-effects

I have a few questions regarding using a random effect in a GAM. First, how do you interpret and communicate the output graph?

[image: mgcv random effect graph for fire]

I have fire modeled as a random effect in this GAM because it is largely a random occurrence at my different field sites and I only noted it as a binary. It wouldn't work as a normal variable since it has too few levels and there is also relatively few sites with fire. However, it greatly improved model variance capture when included so I don't want to simply exclude it. I don't know how to interpret the output and I am also not entirely confident that there wouldn't be another way to include it in the model other than as a random effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The effect has been modelled as a random *slope* if you didn't code it as a factor in the data. The value on the y axis is the estimated slope; it will be a little smaller in absolute value than if you use `Fire` as a linear fixed effect in the model formula because it is being penalised (shrunk) towards zero.

This likely should have been fitted as a binary fixed effect; code `Fire` as a factor with two levels (`Yes`/`No`, or `Burned` / `Unburned` say). Just because a variable represents something that is random over the data doesn't mean it is a suitable random effect; fire here has some average effect and the fixed effect describes that well. There's nothing stopping you from using `Fire` coded as a factor as a random effect via the smooth, but with only two levels it's not going the two intercepts aren't going to be estimate that precisely.

Now, if you had repeated observations on `n` sites and you thought the `Fire` effect varied across the `n` sites then you could do `s(Site, Fire, bs = 're')` where both `Site` and `Fire` are factors and you'll get different `Fire` effects for each `Site`. Then the plot you show would have many points on it as it is a QQ-plot of the estimated values for the effect of `Fire` in each `Site`, hence 1 point per `Site`. Given the way this model is estimated, these are somewhat assumed to be distributed Gaussian with some variance that is inversely proportional to the smoothness parameter selected by `gam()` when fitting this random effect smoother. That's why the default plot is as it is; it's a QQ-plot comparing the observed distribution of estimate values of the random effects against the theoretical expectation.