# Nested sample design in mgcv syntax

Tags: r, mgcv, longitudinal, random-effects

I'm having trouble translating my sample design into the correct mgcv package syntax for random effects.

Here is the set-up: we trawl for fish, once per "collection" site, at the same 12 sites per month (hopefully), for 7 consecutive months, every year (these are my random intercepts, I think). However, sometimes sites in the database are either skipped by accident (NA), or are replaced by back-up sites (which is a near-by site to replace the intended one when poor conditions hinder us from trawling there). There is also a repeated measures aspect to the data wherein many fish lengths are recorded within the same site (this is just a covariate, but thought random intercepts are also for repeated measures). If my goal is to faithfully represent this design, how should I structure my random effects? Something like this (?):

(fSite = factor site; fCYR = factor calendar year)

**s(fSite, bs='re') +
s(fCYR, , bs='re')**

or

**s(fSite, fCYR, bs='re')** <- Does this only work if the same 12 sites are present in each fCYR level?

Data:

```
> dput(station)
structure(list(CYR = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), Month = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), `Coll. Site 1` = c(21, 
23, 22, 23, 22, 23, 22, 22, 21, 68, 23, 22, 22, 70, 20, 23, 22, 
20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 21, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, NA, NA, 22, 22, 22, NA, NA, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22), `Coll. Site 2` = c(40, 
70, 70, 70, 68, 68, 68, 68, 70, 101, 112, 70, 70, 143, 70, 70, 
68, 67, 70, 67, 67, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 
70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 
70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 
70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70), 
    `Coll. Site 3` = c(70, 112, 112, 122, 123, 112, 122, 122, 
    111, 136, 134, 124, 135, 158, 122, 123, 124, 124, 112, 123, 
    123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 
    123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 124, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 
    123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 
    123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 
    123, 123, 123, NA, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123), `Coll. Site 4` = c(147, 
    147, 133, 134, 146, 159, 54, 134, 134, 159, 156, 145, 146, 
    167, 159, 146, 144, 146, 147, 146, 145, 146, 146, 146, 146, 
    146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 145, 146, 146, 146, 146, 
    146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 
    146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 
    146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 
    146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146), `Coll. Site 5` = c(176, 173, 
    168, 168, 169, 172, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 169, 167, 241, 
    169, 172, 146, 168, 168, 169, 167, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 
    168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 
    168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 
    168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 
    168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, NA, 168, 168, 168, 
    168, 168, 168, 168, 168), `Coll. Site 6` = c(241, 258, 241, 
    241, 241, 241, 144, 241, 169, 241, 241, 241, 241, 266, 241, 
    241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 240, 241, 
    241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 
    241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 240, 
    241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 
    241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 241, 
    241, 241, 241, 241), `Coll. Site 7` = c(280, 279, 266, 266, 
    253, 266, 24, 266, 241, 270, 266, 266, 266, 270, 270, 266, 
    266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 257, 266, 
    266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 
    266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 
    257, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 
    266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 
    266, NA, 266), `Coll. Site 8` = c(281, 283, 270, 270, 257, 
    270, NA, 270, 266, 279, 270, 270, 270, 301, 301, 270, 270, 
    270, 270, 270, 270, NA, 270, 270, 270, 270, 265, 270, 270, 
    270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, NA, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 
    270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 266, 
    270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 
    270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 
    270, 270), `Coll. Site 9` = c(314, 302, 301, 314, 301, 301, 
    NA, 301, 270, 301, 301, 301, 301, 402, 402, 301, 301, 301, 
    314, 301, 314, 312, 301, 301, 302, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 
    NA, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 
    301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 
    301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 
    301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 
    301), `Coll. Site 10` = c(401, 314, 303, 609, 314, 402, NA, 
    314, 301, 314, 314, 314, 314, 618, 618, 314, 314, 314, 403, 
    402, 402, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 
    314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 315, 314, 314, 314, 314, 
    314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 
    314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, NA, 314, 314, 314, 
    314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314
    ), `Coll. Site 11` = c(618, 402, 402, 618, 402, 618, NA, 
    402, 314, 402, 402, 402, 402, 314, 266, 402, 402, 402, 609, 
    618, 618, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 
    402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 
    402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 
    402, NA, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 
    402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402, 402
    ), `Coll. Site 12` = c(NA, 621, 618, NA, 621, NA, NA, 618, 
    402, 618, 619, 618, 618, NA, NA, 621, 618, 618, 616, 314, 
    301, 618, 621, 618, 618, 618, 616, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 
    618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 
    618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 
    618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 621, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 
    618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618)), row.names = c(NA, 
-79L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Partial solution; I think I need both. The single term random intercepts capture similarity between data points from the same site and/or year, while the interaction term creates a random intercept for the combination of each unique site|year block and represents the repeated measures bit. Source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542402/how-to-interpret-random-effects-plot-from-mgcv?rq=2

Comment: If you are going to post data, it would help if they were already in the format required for your model (or give the code to get them that way); these are in wide format and need to be in long (tidy) form for modelling (i.e. they don't even contain the Site variable you mention throughout the question). A general rule on [so] is "help us to help you". If you don't provide working code, or clean data (or code to clean it) many users will just walk on by without looking because it's too much hassle to even get to a point where they can begin to see what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Gavin, I added the data in this format in the hopes that it would serve only as a visual aid to the sampling design issue - not the modelling problem, per se.  My apologies.

Comment: But someone who isn't familiar with {mgcv} but who is familiar with mixed effects will likely just move on from your question because to answer it they'd need to see what model matrices `gam()` was constructing from your data and they wouldn't be able to do that without wrangling your data *and* trying to figure out what the `gam()` call you are using is. You'd more than likely have gotten an answer already if you'd included properly structured data and model code (and it always helps to add the [tag:r] tag for questions involving R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this only work if the same 12 sites are present in each `fCYR` level?

Try it and see. tldr: yes, it works; no it doesn't require the same 12 sites to be present in each year. The key thing is that unique sites should be coded uniquely. However, using both the random effect forms you mention in the model can be beneficial as it can lead to a more parsimonious fit.

Assuming your data is in `df` and properly formatted for what I think your model is

```r
library("mgcv")
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")
library("janitor")

df2 <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c(-Month, -CYR), names_to = "site",
             values_to = "value", names_prefix = "^Coll\\. ") |>
janitor::clean_names() |>
mutate(fcyr = factor(cyr), site = factor(site))
```

we can fit three models to compare what random effects are doing:

```r
knots <- list(month = c(0.5, 12.5))
m1 <- gam(value ~ s(month, bs = "cc") +
            s(fcyr, bs = "re") + s(site, bs = "re"),
          data = df2, family = nb(), knots = knots)
m2 <- gam(value ~ s(month, bs = "cc") + s(fcyr, site, bs = "re"),
          data = df2, family = nb(), knots = knots)
m3 <- gam(value ~ s(month, bs = "cc") +
            s(fcyr, bs = "re") + s(site, bs = "re") +
            s(fcyr, site, bs = "re"),
          data = df2, family = nb(), knots = knots)
```

As there are 132 unique (site, year) pairs

```r
> with(df2, nlevels(interaction(fcyr, site, drop = TRUE)))                    
[1] 132
```

`m2` uses almost 131 EDF (one df gets lost due to the model intercept IIRC)

```
> model_edf(m1)                                                               
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  model   edf
  <chr> <dbl>
1 m1     19.8

r$> model_edf(m2)                                                               
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  model   edf
  <chr> <dbl>
1 m2     132.

r$> model_edf(m3)                                                               
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  model   edf
  <chr> <dbl>
1 m3     58.1
```

while `m3` which contains all three ranef terms uses on ~58 EDF.

As your comment speculates, you get a more parsimonious fit to the data if you include the site and year random effects plus their combination than if you just fitted the `site:fcyr` form as per `m2`.

Both `m2` and `m3` allow you to estimate a random intercept for all 132 (site,year) pairs. So what's the difference?

As your comment surmises, the two "main" random effects encode the average effects of each `site` and the average effect of each `year`. The `s(site, fcyr, bs = "re")` term then estimates the deviations from the site and year averages for individual (site,year) pairs. Once you have estimated the average `site` and `year` effects, the deviations around individual sites due to year (or equivalently deviations over years about individual site means) are relatively small. Hence the `s(site,fcyr, bs = "re")` term only uses ~40 EDF; much of the potential deviation is shrunk away because the random `site` and `year` effects are already accounted for in the model.

So in this instance you could use *either* form:

1. `~ s(fcyr, bs = "re") + s(site, bs = "re") + s(fcyr, site, bs = "re")`, or
2. `~ s(fcyr, site, bs = "re")`

but option 1 is more parsimonious. That need not be the case however. If the within site and within year variation is large, it is not inconceivable that the decomposed form (1.) will offer no advantage over 2.

The main thing with random effects is to make sure that the groups are labelled uniquely. Say you have 3 fields and take measurements repeatedly from 6 locations within each field. You wouldn't code the six locations as `loc1`, `loc2`, ..., `loc6` in each field, because the model would think that any row with `location` equal to `loc1` is the same location. Say the fields are labelled `A`, `B` and `C`, you would code the locations as `locA1`, `locA2`, ..., `locB1`, ..., `locC6` to avoid any ambiguity. In the mixed effects software world in R, this kind of question comes up a lot; there, with the way the formula interface to things like `lme()` and `lmer()` work you could get away with the `loc1` coding form *if* you said `location` was nested in `field`. Hence discussions about crossed or nested random effects. That whole discussion goes away if you code your grouping variable correctly.

With *mgcv*, if you used the `loc1` form and then fitted the formula 1. form of the model you'd get things wrong

```r
y ~ s(field, bs="re") + s(location, bs="re") + s(field, location, bs="re")
```

as the `s(location, bs="re")` term would think all observations labelled `loc1` were all the same location ("subject"), when they aren't. In that case, the 2. form of the model would be the correct one

```r
y ~ s(field, location, bs="re")
```

In summary, which form you used really comes down to how you coded your grouping factors and not whether the design is nested or crossed.